# Grails sorting in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails

I have two domains in a Grails application with a one-to-many relationship: Course and Person. One course may have many people. When I view show.gsp for Course, it will show a list of all person's names who are registered for the Course.

I want that list to be sorted alphabetically by last name.  However, each time that I refresh show.gsp, the order of the list changes (can't seem to identify a pattern). I set up a mapping in my Person domain to sort by lastName "asc", but that has no effect.

I had modified the scaffolded show.gsp to display the names in a table along with additional checkboxes. Here is that modified code:

```
<g:if test="${courseInstance?.persons}">
            <br />
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <g:sortableColumn property="person"
                            title="${message(code: 'person.lastName.label', default: 'Person')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="paid"
                            title="${message(code: 'person.paid.label', default: 'Paid')}" />
                        <g:sortableColumn property="attended"
                            title="${message(code: 'person.attended.label', default: 'Attended')}" />
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <g:set var="counter" value="${1}" />
                    <g:each in="${courseInstance.persons}" status="i" var="p">
                        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                            <td>
                                ${counter}
                            </td>
                            <td class="property-value" aria-labelledby="persons-label"><g:link
                                    controller="person" action="show" id="${p.id}">
                                    ${p?.encodeAsHTML()}
                                </g:link></td>
                            <td><g:checkBox name="paid" value="${p.paid}"
                                    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'togglePaid', id:p.id,
                                params:'\'completed=\' + this.checked')}" /></td>
                            <td><g:checkBox name="attended" value="${p.attended}"
                                    onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'toggleAttended', id:p.id,
                                params:'\'completed=\' + this.checked')}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <g:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}" />
                    </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </g:if>
```

Is there any modification I can make either in show.gsp or the domain to have the list sorted alphabetically by default (unless a sortable column is clicked)?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if I remove the custom code added (and just use the scaffolded show.gsp) the problem still occurs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you show how you have it set on the Domain Level? It should like like so...

```
class Person {
    …
    static mapping = {
        sort "lastName"
    }
}
```

Check out the documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html).  If the sorting does seem to be correct but still not working you could try stopping the app and doing a `grails clean` and re-running it.

**UPDATE:**
answer is the comments below...

Comment: Hi Michael, I do already have that in my Person domain, as mentioned above...(sorry, I should have shown code for my domains for clarity). The problem still occurs.

Comment: Hmm, no dice...I have the mapping exactly as you posted in my Person class. I also performed a stop, clean, run multiple times both with my modified code and with just the regular scaffolded views...

Comment: okay.  I would assume that your next issue would be that your one-to-many relationship may be the issue.  It could be returning a java.util.Set which isn't sortable.  Post you domain classes and we'll have a look.

Comment: That was it! My course domain was returning a set. So I added a line before the defining the relationship to return a List: List persons = new ArrayList(); static hasMany = [ persons:Person ]. After adding that it worked. Thanks for your help!